# Logstash reindex elasticsearch Issue

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, reindex

I'm trying to reindex the data by having elasticsearch as input and sending back to elasticsearch as output. The script is running fine but the indexing is going indefinitely. The script is as below

```
input {
    elasticsearch {
                host => "10.0.0.11"
                index => "logstash-2015.02.05"
        }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {

                 host => "10.0.0.11"
                 protocol => "http"
                 cluster => "logstash"
                 node_name => "logindexer"
                 index => "logstash-2015.02.05_new"
                }
}
```

This means if I have 200 docs under logstash-2015.02.05 index then it creates duplicate records in logstash-2015.02.05_new and keeps going until I stop the logstash agent. Is there a way to just restrict the documents in new index to have exactly the same as the old index? Pls help.

Comment: This isn't the best way to reindex data. Use kopf on your elasticsearch cluster, or just run the reindex command http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/reindex.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The idea to reindex was to manipulate the fields during the reindexing process and not just to have same replica of index. I found the answer to call groovy scripts and use scan/scroll api through elastic REST handler by writing a custom plugin. There's no reindex command in elasticsearch.

Comment: Correction, there is no reindex command natively. Look at scan&scroll or use a plugin that gives you a reindex command. https://github.com/karussell/elasticsearch-reindex